# Increase the height of a selectinput

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to expand the size of a `selectInput()` by increasing its height? Basically I want all the available choices to be displayed and make the selectinput box bigger.

```
#ui.r
fluidPage(

  # Copy the line below to make a select box 
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
    choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
    selected = 1),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

)
#server.r
function(input, output) {

  # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
  output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

}
```

Comment: Maybe try `checkboxGroupInput` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below and try if this works:

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      fluidRow(

        selectInput("distance", label=NULL, choices = list("1" = 1, "2" = 2), selected = 1),
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".selectize-input {height: 150px; width: 550px; font-size: 50px;}")))
      )

)
server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here you can set size of selectInput as `height` and `width` .

With checkboxGroupInput:

```
library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(

    # Copy the line below to make a select box 
    checkboxGroupInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
                selected = 1),

    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

  )
  #server.r
 server<- function(input, output) {

    # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With radioButton:

```
ui<-fluidPage(

    # Copy the line below to make a select box 
    radioButtons("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
                choices = list("Choice 1" = 1, "Choice 2" = 2, "Choice 3" = 3), 
                selected = 1),

    hr(),
    fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value")))

  )
  #server.r
 server<- function(input, output) {

    # You can access the value of the widget with input$select, e.g.
    output$value <- renderPrint({ input$select })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: it increases the box but still only the first choice is displayed.

Comment: `selectInput` in a function which by default generates a drop down list.

Comment: I have added your example with `checkboxGroupInput` to satisfy your use case. @firmo23

Comment: You can also use `radioButtons` for your use case @firmo23, as mentioned with an example above.

Comment: Accept and upvote the answer, if it resolved the problem